# Socket Java - Client receives a wrong information

Tags: java, eclipse, sockets, server, client

I am trying to send two numbers via Socket. The Server receive the numbers and I make some calculation, but when I send back to Client the result, the Client receive a number which he send it.

Where I doing wrong beceause I don't understand?

Client.java

```
public class Client {
    private static Socket socket;
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            String host = "localhost";
            int port = 25010;
            InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);
            socket = new Socket(address, port);

            //Send the message to the server
            OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);

            String number = "2";
            String number2 = "5";

            String sendMessage = number + "\n";
            String sendMessage2 = number2 + "\n";
            bw.write(sendMessage);
            bw.write(sendMessage2);
            bw.flush();
            System.out.println("Message sent to the server:\n" + sendMessage + sendMessage2);

            //Get the return message from the server
            InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String message = br.readLine();
            System.out.println("Message received from the server : " + message);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            //Closing the socket
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Server.java

```
public class Server {
    private static Socket socket;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            int port = 25010;
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            System.out.println("Server Started and listening to the port " + port);
            ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();

            //Server is running always. This is done using this while(true) loop
            while(true) {
                //Reading the message from the client
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));     // primeste mesaj de la client
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));   // transmite raspuns catre client
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

                String inputLine;
                while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    out.println(inputLine);
                    arr.add(inputLine.trim());
                }

                System.out.println("Message received from client is:");
                for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.println(arr.get(i));
                }

                //Return message
                String returnMessage = null;
                try {
                    int numberInIntFormat = 0;
                    int num = 1;
                    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
                        System.out.println(arr.get(i));
                        numberInIntFormat = Integer.parseInt(arr.get(i));
                        num = num * numberInIntFormat;
                    }
                    arr.clear();
                    returnMessage = String.valueOf(num);
                } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
                    //Input was not a number. Sending proper message back to client.
                    returnMessage = "Please send a proper number\n";
                }

                //Sending the response back to the client.
                bw.write(returnMessage);
                bw.flush();
                System.out.println("returnMessage = " + returnMessage);
                System.out.println("Message sent to the client is "+ returnMessage);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch(Exception e) {}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your console outputs.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a better method:

```
while (br.ready() && (inputLine = br.readLine()) != null)
```

This tell that to read the buffer if it is something to read.

With the response from @John Bollinger, the buffer read only up to first line break, so if you try to parse a String which contains a line break, you will get out when appear the line break.

With br.ready() it will parse all the String and will get out at the end of buffer.

Comment: No. It will exit the loop when there is no data available to be read without blocking. This is rarely what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your server code echoes everything it reads from the client back to the client before it does anything else with it:

```
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));     // primeste mesaj de la client
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));   // transmite raspuns catre client
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        out.println(inputLine);    // <-- HERE
        arr.add(inputLine.trim());
    }
```

It is unsurprising that the client receives what the server sent.

Comment: I wiped that line which you tell me, and now the Server don't send back any message... I'm waiting and I'm waiting...

Comment: Well, that would be because the server has no way to know that the client has finished sending input.  `BufferedReader.readLine()` returns `null` at end-of-file, but end-of-file is not reached on a network connection until the connection is closed.

Answer (score 0):

```
String inputLine;
while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    arr.add(inputLine.trim());
}
```

With this change, the output is:

**Server:**

```
Server Started and listening to the port 25010
```

**Client:**

```
Message sent to the server:
2
5
```

And now the Server is 'blocked' in while loop and the Client don't recive any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Client:

```
public class Client {
    private static Socket socket;
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            String host = "localhost";
            int port = 25010;
            InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);
            socket = new Socket(address, port);

            //Send the message to the server
            OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);

            String number = "2";
            String number2 = "5";

            String sendMessage = number + "\n";
            String sendMessage2 = number2 + "\n";
            bw.write(sendMessage);
            bw.write(sendMessage2);
            bw.newLine();  // You need to send a special line for say to the server: "Hey, I have done";
            bw.flush();
            System.out.println("Message sent to the server:\n" + sendMessage + sendMessage2);

            //Get the return message from the server
            InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String message = br.readLine();
            System.out.println("Message received from the server : " + message);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            //Closing the socket
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Server:

```
public class Server {
    private static Socket socket;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            int port = 25010;
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            System.out.println("Server Started and listening to the port " + port);
            ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();

            //Server is running always. This is done using this while(true) loop
            while(true) {
                //Reading the message from the client
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));     // primeste mesaj de la client
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));   // transmite raspuns catre client
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

                String inputLine;
                while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null && inputLine.length() > 0) { // You need to stop loop when you get empty line
                   // out.println(inputLine);
                    arr.add(inputLine.trim());
                    System.out.println("Message received from client is:"+inputLine.trim());
                }

                System.out.println("Message received from client is:");

                //Return message
                String returnMessage = null;
                try {
                    int numberInIntFormat = 0;
                    int num = 1;
                    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
                        System.out.println(arr.get(i));
                        numberInIntFormat = Integer.parseInt(arr.get(i));
                        num = num * numberInIntFormat;
                    }
                    arr.clear();
                    returnMessage = String.valueOf(num);
                } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
                    //Input was not a number. Sending proper message back to client.
                    returnMessage = "Please send a proper number\n";
                }

                //Sending the response back to the client.
                bw.write(returnMessage+"\n"); // You need to add '\n' otherwise readLine never gets;
                bw.flush();
                System.out.println("returnMessage = " + returnMessage);
                System.out.println("Message sent to the client is "+ returnMessage);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch(Exception e) {}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For this to be a useful answer (to the community), you would need to explain what you have changed, and why.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I did. Into the code I added some comments